# Get selected row edittext value on a button's click in Android

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have created table layout as follows:

[image]

Now  my requirement is:
I have number of rows just like in above Image. I want to access edittext value after it get edited in onClick of button which is placed out of table layout. i.e., I want the table row id & childs of that row into onclick of a button which is placed out of that table layout.
Anybody please suggest me idea to achieve this. 
Code used to create table layout is:

```
TableLayout tl=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.mytable);
            tl.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

            for( int i=0;i<passediduniq.size();i++){



                final TableRow tr=new TableRow(MyActivity.this);
     //allchilds as in image

}
```

Comment: Its unclear what you are trying to achieve.Provide more details.

Comment: I have a button with name "update" outside of that tablelayout.need to get edittext value which is edited , row id of tablelayout & access this data from Onclicklistener of update button.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is so unclear as i understood this may help you.

```
EditText editText=(EditText)arg1.findViewById(R.id.edit_list_details);
```

Now get the text from edit text

```
editText.gettext()
```

inside button click .

hope this may help.

Comment: when you use that edit text you can get the position of that particular EditText